# How to show MQ client list by Java?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

Is it possible to show all clients of a MQ server (or MQ queue manager, or channel) by Java? Because there are too many connections sometimes and I need to monitor it.

I checked the API of com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager
(https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQQueueManager.html)
I can use it to get queue depth, but I cannot get the client connection information (ex: IP address) of it.

If it's impossible to get IP address, could we get "connection count" only?

Comment: maybe there is a REST API for this?

Comment: You would use the IBM MQ PCF interface for this.   There are many Java examples of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use MQ PCF via Java.

```
request = new PCFMessage(CMQCFC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_CHANNEL_STATUS);
request.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME, "TEST.CHL");
request.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_INSTANCE_TYPE, CMQC.MQOT_CURRENT_CHANNEL);
request.addParameter(CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_INSTANCE_ATTRS,
                     new int []
                     {
                        CMQCFC.MQCACH_CHANNEL_NAME,
                        CMQCFC.MQCACH_CONNECTION_NAME,
                        CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_STATUS,
                        CMQCFC.MQIACH_CHANNEL_SUBSTATE,
                        CMQCFC.MQIACH_MSGS,
                        CMQCFC.MQCACH_LAST_MSG_DATE,
                        CMQCFC.MQCACH_LAST_MSG_TIME,
                        CMQCFC.MQCACH_CHANNEL_START_DATE,
                        CMQCFC.MQCACH_CHANNEL_START_TIME,
                        CMQCFC.MQIACH_BYTES_SENT,
                        CMQCFC.MQIACH_BYTES_RECEIVED,
                        CMQCFC.MQIACH_BUFFERS_SENT,
                        CMQCFC.MQIACH_BUFFERS_RECEIVED,
                        CMQCFC.MQIACH_MCA_STATUS,
                        CMQCFC.MQCACH_MCA_JOB_NAME,
                        CMQCFC.MQCACH_MCA_USER_ID
                     } );

responses = agent.send(request);
```

Comment: Is "responses" is a CMQCFC ? I try to find the API document, but not sure what's the connection count or connection list. Could you advise it? https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/constants/CMQCFC.html

Comment: OMG.  First start here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q030980_.htm  - secondly, I copied & pasted the code snippet from my open source project called MQ Channel Monitor (http://www.capitalware.com/mqcm_overview.html) so go and download the source code AND READ THE MQ PCF manual.

Comment: It works, I use this code to get responses.length for connection count, and MQCACH_CONNECTION_NAME to get the IP address, thanks.